# Changing the theme in eclipse kepler fails

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse Kepler (4.3.2) trying to change the theme of eclipse in settings.

When i open that setting eclipse fails saying:

[image]

After a second click on appearance the setting opens but with no choosable element in the theme selectbox.

[image]

The error does not change when I install theme plugins like:
- moonrise ui plugin
- eclipse theme plugin

I also tried to copy themes to \dropins\plugins folder as described in some tutorials, but this does not not work too

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message about the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Color IDE Pack and the Eclipse Color Theme 1.0.0 (under Eclipse Marketplace > Installed)? I use that exact same version of Kepler with Eclipse Moonrise and it works just fine.

Also, have you tried changing workspace to a completely clean one? Set it to an empty folder so it "generates everything again".

If that doesn't work id suggest you to download eclipse again and see if it works, as a last solution.

Also, as a side note, you could consider moving to Eclipse Mars, which is the latest version of Eclipse, I've recently moved from Kepler to Mars and I've had no problems so far.